# Remove class after timeout

Tags: jquery

This function adds a class to a element.

How do I remove the class after a timeout of 2s?

```
  $('input[type=checkbox], input[type=radio]').click(function(){
    if(this.checked){
      $('#slct-'+this.value).addClass('active');
    }
  });
```

Comment: In the duplicate, change `800` to `2000`

Answer (score 1):

```
setTimeout(function(){
 $('#slct-'+this.value).removeClass('active');
}, 2000);
```